# How can we show a data set satisfies the manifold assumption?

Tags: manifolds, machine-learning

In machine learning, we often assume that a data set lies on a low-dimensional manifold (the manifold assumption), but is there any formal proof saying that assuming the data set satisfies certain conditions, it can be shown that it indeed forms (approximately) a low-dimensional manifold?

For example, given a data sequence $\{\mathbf{X}_1 \ldots \mathbf{X}_n\}$ where $\mathbf{X_i} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (say the sequence of face images with different angles) and a corresponding label sequence $\{ y_1 \ldots y_n\}$ where $y_1 \preceq y_2 \ldots \preceq y_n$  (say the angles of the face sequence). Suppose when $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ are very close, their labels $y_i$ and $y_{i+1}$ are also very close, we can imagine that it is likely that $\{\mathbf{X}_1 \ldots \mathbf{X}_n\}$ lies on a low-dimensional manifold. Is this true? If so, how can we prove it? Or what conditions does the sequence need to satisfy so that the manifold assumption can be proven to be true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I must be missing something because finitely many vectors can always be placed on a one dimensional manifold, indeed they form a zero dimensional manifold themselves. Can you explain or link to how "face images with different angles" are related to $X_i$, what the labels $y_i$ stand for, and what the "manifold assumption" is exactly.

Comment: The face sequence example I mentioned here comes from the Isomap paper (http://web.mit.edu/cocosci/Papers/sci_reprint.pdf, fig 1(A)), and here $y_t$ is the angle of the face pose. The finite sequence $X_i$ are indeed samples from an underlying distribution, so I guess the questions is when can we assume that the support of the distribution forms a low-dimensional smooth manifold (in other words, the data is not scattered all over the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^d$, but constrained on the smooth manifold)?

Comment: "All of the images lie on an intrinsically three-dimensional manifold, or constraint surface, that can be parameterized by two pose variables plus an azimuthal lighting angle". It seems to me that this simply reflects the fact that a face is 2-dimensional plus one more dimension is needed for how it is lit. "Coordinates capture the intrinsic degrees of
freedom of a data set", the rest is noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any necessary and / or sufficient condition to prove that a finite set of data in $\mathbb R^n$ is actually contained in a smooth submanifold $\mathcal M$ of low dimension.

Actually, modern studies try to identify the topological structure lying behind a given set of data (yes, we have to move down to the topological level) using algebraic topology and, in particular, information coming from [persistent homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_homology). This some sort of backward reconstruction: the topological information gathered by the methodology are used for inference or to further characterize clusters of data.
A survey is contained in
[this nice paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-02/S0273-0979-09-01249-X/S0273-0979-09-01249-X.pdf). This new machinery is quite powerful, as it is more flexible than MDS and PCA and allows the user to introduce functions to control the simplicial complex definition which is at the core of the method itself.

In some applications the authors showed that the given data lie on a smooth manifold; the machinery works at the algebraic topology level, though.

If you are interested in this backward reconstruction, then I would start by considering the nice case of the noisy circle introduced in [here](http://comptop.stanford.edu/u/preprints/mapperPBG.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your answering! I was aware of Gunnar Carlsson's work and I really need to learn more about algebraic topology.

Comment: You are welcome & welcome to Math SE :). Please, feel free to flag and / or upvote the answer if you found it useful. Carlsson's paper  can be quite difficult at a first reading. I recommend to have a look at the paper describing the MAPPER  and the examples ivi contained. It is more accessible and allowed me to understand the ideas behind the method.